# change word to number when inserting into DB

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

I am wondering if there is a way to change a form field to a number when saving to a MySQL DB.

Here is my code

```
<label>Account Type:</lable><select>
<option>Administrator</option>
<option>Master </option>
</select>
```

what i am trying to do is, if administrator is selected save this as `0` and if master is selected save at `1`

Comment: Why not just use the `value` attribute of the `option` element?

Comment: Of course, you also need to give your `<select>` tag a `name` attribute in order to properly use it as a form element in non-scripted HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this : set `value` for `option` so when you select Administrator it will store `0` and for master it will store `1`

```
<option value="0">Administrator</option>
<option value="1">Master </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

[HTML Forms 101 on the Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms)